# How to convert indentation from 2 spaces to 4 spaces

Tags: python, automation, edit, indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HOWTO: Fix Python Indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/howto-fix-python-indentation)

I have Python library where only **2 spaces** indentation was used. I need automated way to convert all files to **4 spaces** indentation. Is there any tool/script/editor for that?

Plz don't suggest Emacs.

Comment: What OS are you on?  You could do it with Python, but this sort of thing is usually done with a script in your relevant cli.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625294/how-do-i-autoformat-some-python-code-to-be-correctly-formatted

Comment: Please check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/howto-fix-python-indentation.

Comment: You also can replace 2-space with 4-space. https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/c7rs4c/comment/eshi16g/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the [reindent script](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Reindent/0.1.1) by Tim Peters, it was designed specifically for converting Python files to 4-space indentation.

For users with Python 3.9 or newer consider using [reindent latest version](https://pypi.org/project/reindent/).

Comment: Only works in Python 2.7, which can be pretty painful if you haven't had that version setup for a long time.

Comment: Now, it works in Python 3.7+.