# Copy Pasting Code from Sublime Text onto console(rails)

Tags: sublimetext3, rails-console

When I try copy pasting code from my Sublime Text 3 editor onto the console, something goes wrong. I get the following message:

Display all 802 possibilities? (y or n)

While there is no problem when I copy paste the code from vim.

It seems some special characters are copied from sublime onto the Rails Console. What are they, how can I avoid this problem. I don't want to open up vim every time I need to do this.

Comment: It's probably [tab] `0x9` chars.

Comment: How to fix the problem?

Comment: I don't use Sublime Text, but looking at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14773271/78845 converting tabs to spaces seems fairly trivial.