# Run python script simply without adding directory to bashrc?

Tags: python, indentation, pep8

I am going away from tabs to spaces and would like to convert my current *.py files to this convention. It appears [reindent.py](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1024489/943773) is the recommended way of doing this.

After installing it on Ubuntu using `sudo apt-get install python-examples`, it ended up in `/usr/share/doc/pythonx.x/examples/Tools/scripts/reindent.py`.

Is there a preferred/recommended way of running such scripts without referencing the directory, and perhaps without adding that directory to my Path variable?

I hope to run this on single files and in batch, such as described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625294/how-do-i-autoformat-some-python-code-to-be-correctly-formatted#comment2638395_2625361):

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" | xargs python reindent.py --nobackup
```

Comment: Just copy the file, or symlink it.

Comment: Is there a way that might persist if I were to re-install my environment after a reformat, etc?

Comment: No. But you'll use the script *once* or perhaps twice to convert some files, not all the time.

Comment: yeah, i suppose so. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `easy_install reindent` or `pip install reindent`, and then it will be on your path as command `reindent`

Comment: This is great. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the file, or symlink it.

It is a stand-alone script, it does not depend on anything else in `scripts` directory, so it can live *anywhere*. Symlinking or copying it into a directory that is on your `$PATH` would enable you to run it without any path prefix (provided the executable bit is set, `chmod +x reindent.py`).