# Can you deparse Python code to get more Pythonic code?

Tags: python

Having moved from Perl to Python one of the things I miss is "Deparse".  It not only reformats perl code, but it reduces the number of parens and even changes older features to equivalent newer features.

For example:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'if (($x == $b) || ($foo == $bar )) { &thing };'
if ($x == $b or $foo == $bar) {
    &thing;
}
-e syntax OK
```

Notice that it not just formats it, it removed unnecessary parens and turned older syntax (`||`) to newer syntax (`or`).

Is there anything similar for Python?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625294/how-do-i-autoformat-some-python-code-to-be-correctly-formatted) might help.

Comment: There's also [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) which updates 2.x code to be compliant with 3.x, but I'm not aware of anything similar which works across minor versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I autoformat some Python code to be correctly formatted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625294/how-do-i-autoformat-some-python-code-to-be-correctly-formatted)

Comment: `||` isn't "old" and `or` isn't "new". They just have different precedence. Deparse prints out the parse tree that the original code is internally compiled to... at some point in that process, converting from high-precedence `||` + parens to low-precedence `or` was done.

Comment: Correct.  The replacement was done to take advantage of the precedence of `or`, thus eliminating many parens. Excellent point. I was sloppy in my language and you are absolutely correct.  (That said... I should point out that the code in the example was written back before Perl had the `or` operator and I used Deparse to upgrade to the newer and better way of doing things. However, it is likely that a large fraction of the people reading this page weren't born when Perl didn't have `or`.)