# Unexpected Indent Error on Python SQLITE

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm working on a Thinkful challenge. Here are the instructions:

> Write a script called "database.py" to print out the cities with the
>   July being the warmest month. Your script must:
>
> Connect to the database  Create the cities and weather tables (HINT:
>   first pass the statement DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ; to remove
>   the table before you execute the CREATE TABLE ... statement) Insert data into the two tables  Join the data together  Load into a pandas DataFrame

Here is the error

```
Aschs-MacBook-Air:dbs aschharwood$ python database.py
  File "database.py", line 20
    cols = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Here is the code:

```
import sqlite3 as lite

# Here you connect to the database. The `connect()` method returns a connection object.
con = lite.connect('get_started.db')

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cities")
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS weather")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE cities (name text, state text)")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE weather (city text, year integer, warm_month text, cold_month text)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO cities VALUES('Washington', 'DC')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO cities VALUES('Houston', 'TX')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO weather VALUES('Washington', 2013, 'July', 'January',)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO weather VALUES('Houston', 2013, 'July', 'January',)")
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM cities LEFT OUTER JOIN weather ON name = city")

    rows = cur.fetchall() #grabbing all the rows
    cols = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)


    print(df)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Your help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: The IndentationError might be due to mixing tabs and spaces. Run `python -t database.py`. The `-t` flag tells python to warn if the source file mixes tabs and spaces for indentation.

Comment: If it turns out that the IndentationError is due to mixing tabs and spaces, you could use [autope8 or reindent.py](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2625361/190597) to convert the tabs to spaces.

Comment: This is definitely the issue. Seemed to have happened when I did the copy and paste from one .py file to another. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that this was a copy paste issue in my text editor, Sublime Text. I copied some code from one file to another. And while it did not look like there was an indent issue, the text editor seemed to be reading it as so.