# Install python 3 modules as system executables

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I want to install the `autopep8` module for python 3 and be able to use it as a command line tool. But installing it this way, as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13761026/1439597), using `pip3` instead:

```
pip3 install autopep8
```

... does not do the trick: when I try to call `autopep8` from the command line, I get a "command not found" error and a suggestion to install the `python-autopep8` package.

```
kenny@localhost:~$ pip3 install autopep8
Collecting autopep8
Collecting pep8>=1.5.7 (from autopep8)
  Using cached pep8-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pep8, autopep8
Successfully installed autopep8-1.2.2 pep8-1.7.0
kenny@localhost:~$ autopep8
The program 'autopep8' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python-autopep8
```

But this package is for python 2.7! And I could not find a `python3-autopep8` one.

Is there a way to install python 3 modules (using `pip3`, for example) as executables, in the same manner that you would do, say, `npm install -g`?

Comment: you can use the `-m` flag: `python -m autopep8`

Comment: are you sure you installed autopep8 without errors and you can `import autopep8` from python3? It's sufficient to `pip3 install autopep8` to get autopep8 binary on my system. Also did you install it system-wide or in your $HOME folder (`--user` option) ? Did you use virtualenv?

Comment: I added my console output when installing and calling autopep8. And yes, when I import it in python 3 I get no errors.

Comment: Here is my output from installing autopep8 (fresh docker image of ubuntu 16.04) http://pastebin.com/6YKicwnS As you can see `autopep8` is installed to `/usr/local/bin/autopep8`. Maybe you should also try `-vvv` option to make output of pip3 more verbose?

Comment: So apparently it installed the binary in `$HOME/.local/bin`. But I can assure you I did not use `--user`

Answer (score 0):

try this command for installation

```
pip install --upgrade autopep8
```

and to use it try

```
autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive <filename>
```

to modify a file in place with aggressive level 2.
Remember that autopep8 needs pep8

Comment: output of that second command: `The program 'autopep8' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install python-autopep8`

Comment: then type it and tell me... and actually i think that the command is:
    sudo apt-get install python-autopep8