# How to auto convert % string formatting to modern .format() method

Tags: python, refactoring, string-formatting, autopep8

I'm looking for a way to convert obsolete `%` string formatting operator to `format()` function in python3 code.

```
ugly = 'Exception: the %s is over %+f' % (t, value)
good = 'Exception: the {} is over {:+f}'.format(e, value)
```

Sure, I use [autopep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8/0.9.7) on save (via PyDev), but it seems that there is no option for turning on desirable conversion. The closest is an `W690` option:

```
W690 - Fix various deprecated code (via lib2to3).
```

But it does not work, as well as explicit run of [lib2to3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/2to3.html). Any solutions are welcome; better if the tool can be integrated into eclipse / pydev, like `autopep8`.

Comment: May be it should be asked in a different way, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625294/how-do-i-autoformat-some-python-code-to-be-correctly-formatted ?

Comment: `%` string interpolation isn't obsolete. But if you _really_ want to replace it with something new then why bother with `format` when you can use f-strings? Eg, `f'Exception: the {t} is over {value:+f}'`

Comment: @cdarke I agree that it is not obsolete; the `format` is just my preference: I do believe that it makes code more readable, and easier for i18n. @2Ring it worth bothering unless python 3.6 is alpha released; but for sure, I'm waiting for the f-string feature, it looks awesome

Comment: @SergeyBelash: I have been playing with f-strings this morning (I have 3.6.0b).  The syntax is similar in some ways to Ruby, but the formatting makes them more powerful.

Comment: @SergeyBelash:  I was doing something unrelated and realised that the `%` formatting has no alternative for bytes objects.  Bytes objects don't have a `.format()` method.  So `%` is certainly not obsolete.